# Convert an array of Object's specific key Values to Comma-Separated String

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do we Convert an Object's specific key Values to Comma-Separated String  , I can convert when it is an array but my issue is that my data is an array of objects , so I wanna convert every id to an array of strings like an example below.

#current code - just initial idea

```
console.log(['a', 'b', 'c'].join(','));
```

#example object

```
data = [
    {
        "id": 496,
    },
    {
        "id": 381,
    }
]
```

#expected result

```
  '496,381'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the items of your array of objects, to extract the value of their `id` key:

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
data.map(item => item.id).join()
```